# facing issue in redirection to asset page in my below code

Tags: angular

```
if (this.uuid) {
this.apiService.deleteAsset(this.uuid).subscribe((res) => {
        const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
        dialogConfig.data = res;

        if (dialogConfig.data.status == 'Success') {
            this.router.navigate(['/assets'], {
                    relativeTo: this.route
                }

            );
        }

        this.dialog.open(MessageComponent, dialogConfig);
    }

);
```

}

Not redirecting to the /asset page in my below code. Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: {path: 'assets', component: DatatableComponent, data: {title: 'Data Table Component'}},     yes i have implemented app routing. The problem is when i call above delete function in res(response) i am getting success status. before navigate to /assets, this.dialog.open(MessageComponent is opening. so i need to navigate to /assets page before opening dailog MessageComponent.

Answer (score 0):

you have any routing to show? 
you need to have a path: 'asset' inside routing app

Regards

Comment: yes i have implemented app routing. The problem is when i call above delete function in res(response) i am getting success status. before navigate to /assets, this.dialog.open(MessageComponent is opening. so i need to navigate to /assets page before opening dailog MessageComponent.

Comment: The point is, you want him to get there and not open the dialogue? just add "return;" inside the if, So he left the function before opening the dialogue

Comment: added return but no luck. No navigation also no dailog